# How to remove only adjacent duplicates in an array of integers in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, duplicates

My implementation:

```
extension Array where Element:Equatable {
    func removeDuplicates() -> [Element] {
        var result = [Element]()

        for value in self {
            if result.contains(value) == false {
                let r = result.append(value)       
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
let arrayOfInts = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1].reverse()
for element in arrayOfInts.removeDuplicates(){
    print(element)
}
```

I would like to perform operations on the array after the adjacent integers have been removed.

Comment: Hi. I don't get what you need here, your question is quite unclear. I think `let arrayOfUniqueInts = arrayOfInt.removeDuplicates()` is the array you want to deal with but I'm not sure what do you need with adjacent things... Could you help us help you please ?

Comment: Yes, you understood it well. I first want to take in my array and remove the adjacent duplicates in it. Then I would like to mutate it and still return the array with the removed duplicates in the mutated order. Here, I have mentioned it as reversed.

Comment: Why did you reverse the array? And what does that have to do with the removing adjacent duplicate problem? I'm a bit confused by that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply solved by adding the elements of the current array to a new array but only appending the current element if it's not equal to the last element to take care of the duplicate adjacent problem.
Try this solution.

```
extension Array where Element:Equatable {
func removeDuplicates()->[Element]{
    guard !self.isEmpty else { return [] }
    var noDuplicates = [Element]()

    for (index, element) in self.enumerated(){
        if index > 0{

            if element != noDuplicates.last{

                noDuplicates.append(element)
                   }
        }
        else{
            noDuplicates.append(element)
        }


    }

    return noDuplicates
}
}
```

EDIT: Also if you're having trouble with using this extension on the `ReversedCollection` after you reverse the array it's because Swift recognizes it as being different from an `Array` type. Once you reverse an `Array` it no longer is an array it becomes a separate type called  `ReversedCollection`. If you want to apply this extension to `ReversedCollection` types as well as arrays, you need to create an extension that's not limited to arrays and includes both `Reversed Collection` and `Array` types or convert the `ReversedCollection` into an `Array`

```
extension Collection where Element:Equatable {
```

Or

```
let arrayOfInts = Array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1].reversed())
for element in arrayOfInts.removeDuplicates(){
    print(element)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any other way to go about this without being have to be able to call on the Array every time I pass in the array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean can you elaborate?

Comment: The extension to the Collections doesn't require you to call an array at all if your question is related to that

Comment: What would you mean by an extension to Collections? Is there a way I could call on two extensions and call on one method to execute them? The aim is to not define or pass in the keyword "Array" when calling on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension is defined on array and reversed returns a reversed view into an array so you need to decay into an actual array.  See solution below.

```
extension Array where Element:Equatable {
  func removeConsecutiveDuplicates() -> [Element] {
    var previousElement: Element? = nil
    return reduce(into: []) { total, element in
      defer {
        previousElement = element
      }
      guard previousElement != element else {
        return
      }
      total.append(element)
    }
  }
}
let arrayOfInts = Array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1].reversed())
for element in arrayOfInts.removeConsecutiveDuplicates() {
    print(element)
}
```

EDIT: I should add to remove consecutive elements its sufficient to just memoize the last element as in my example.  If you want all duplicates then use a `Set<Element>` and not a `[Element]` as in your example because contains on a set is O(C) but its O(n) on an array.

Comment: That's a great solution. But once I delete Array () in arrayOfInts = Array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1].reversed()), it gives me the same error as  """error: value of type 'ReversedCollection<[Int]>' has no member 'removeConsecutiveDuplicates'"""

Comment: @DDD Because once you reverse an ```Array``` it no longer is an array it becomes a separate type called  ```ReversedCollection```. If you want to apply this extension to ```ReversedCollection``` types as well as arrays, you need to create an extension that's not limited to arrays and includes both ```Reversed Collection``` and ```Array``` types or convert the ```ReversedCollection``` into an ```Array```

Comment: If I have to pass in the array at all times would I have to write a method without the "Extends"? The idea was to pass in an array and mutate it whenever needed without having to call on it. Thanks