# Is there a way I could iterate over elements in Swift while using method names?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
let x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1].reversed()
for element in x.method_name() {
    print(element)
}
```

This returns

> Value of type 'ReversedCollection<[Int]>' has no member 'method_name'.

Why? How do I reference the method I have created and have it do the functions I need it to do?

However, if I use the below, the problem seems to disappear. I would just like to pass in an array and do let the function do all, i.e.:

```
let x = Array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1].reversed())
```

Comment: _Where_ have you created the method `method_name`?

Comment: So, I had created the method name seperately as an extension to an Array

Comment: `extension Array where Element:Equatable {
    
    func method_name() -> [Element] {

            total.append(element)
        }
    }
}`

Comment: That method doesn't make much sense. What is `total`? What is `element`? Its signature says it returns an array, yet it doesn't. Note that you can [edit] your question.

Comment: Yes, its signature says it returns an array, but when I use the .reversed() on it, it seems to be converting the array into a reversed collection.

Comment: It was just a boilerplate method I had inserted. The method works well on just arrays, the real problem only occurs when I try to modify the array and pass the method on to it.

Comment: Can you please include full code to reproduce the problem - in the question? How do you define `method_name`? How do you modify array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you don't fully understand the motivation behind this overload of `reversed` returning a [`ReversedCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/reversedcollection) instead of an `Array`, a `ReversedCollection` is just a "reversed view" of your original array. It is not a reversed copy of the original array. This is to save time and space, like a "lazy" collection. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558390/why-does-the-reverse-function-in-the-swift-standard-library-return-reverserand) for more details.

This is why you need the `Array(...)` initialiser to turn the reversed collection back into an array. You are opting out of the laziness.

On the other hand, there is another overload of `reversed` that returns an `Array` directly. Normally this overload is not selected because it is defined in a less specific type - `Sequence`, as opposed to `Array`. You need to give enough information about the type to use this overload:

```
let x: [Int] = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1].reversed()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Incase, the list had strings or any other data type, how would I go about defining "x" to accept all these data types within the array?

Comment: Or instead can I ask my method to do this for me? A similar link is provided below LINK: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382540/how-to-remove-only-adjacent-duplicates-in-an-array-of-integers-in-swift/59383218?noredirect=1#comment104983602_59383218]

Comment: @DDD You mean "ask your method to convert the reversed collection to an array for you"? Well yeah that would work, just write your method as an extension on `ReversedCollection` instead. But your method might violate the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).